# Use holoeverywhere in combination with actionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I am having trouble using the HoloEverywhere library.
At first, I was just using ActionbarSherlock. Now, I would like to implement the holo theme on older devices aswell.

So I downloaded the library, and linked add the project to my main project as library, just like I did with SherlockActionBar.

But once I linked the library, I am getting errors:

[image]

I don't know how to solve this. Also, now my base theme extends from a Sherlock theme. How could I both use the sherlock and holo theme?

I've searched for a solution all day but couldn't fix my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) works with [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/index.html) and not with [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock).

You must remove ActionBarShelock and follow the [Basic migration on HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Basic-migration-on-HoloEverywhere) steps. The `ActionBar` will appear "magically".

If you **really** want to use ABS you can download [HoloEverywhere v1.6.8](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/tree/v1.6.8) but this is an old version with known bugs and it doesn't have support.